# How can I show multiple gates/entrances using Google Places/Directions API?

Tags: swift, google-maps, google-places-api, google-directions-api, google-places-autocomplete

We are using Places API to show predicted addresses (Swift language).
[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvaXb.png)

Now we have to display all entrances\gates of the places (if they are available) [like in this app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XURV.png)

Is it possible to make it in Google PlacesAPI or we need to use something else?

Comment: This information is not currently supported by the Google Maps Platform APIs. But, we have a feature request in Google Issue Tracker to add this functionality. 

To register your interest in this issue, please visit the Issue Tracker at the link below, and star the issue. This will subscribe you to receive technical updates on the issue. You can view and star the issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/68194442